# Why my website is re rendering several times while typing on the text input?

Tags: reactjs, forms, use-state

I am building a react application in which user inputs their name, but whenever I type any word into the *input filed* it re renders. I have tried **useCallback** and **memo** but it is of no use.

The context api is used to pass the name.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useContext, memo, useRef } from "react";
import "./login.css";
import { AuthContext } from "./context";

const Login = () => {
  const renders = useRef(0);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  
   const {
     authContext: { logins },
   } = useContext(AuthContext);

  
  const inputEvent = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setName(e.target.value);
    },
    [setName]
  );

   const buttonClicked = () => {
       console.log(data);
       if (name.length > 0) {
         logins(name);
         localStorage.setItem("user", name);
       } else {
         alert("Please enter your name");
       }
     };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="login">
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Coupon Collector</h2>
        <form className="nameField">
          <input
            className="inputField"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={inputEvent}
          />
        </form>
        <div>renders {renders.current++}</div>
        <div className="buttonDiv">
           <button onClick={buttonClicked} className="button">
            Let's Go
          </button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: The way you have it setup every time the input changes, the callback will change the state, which will cause the component to rerender. So first, why do you care? If just learning this is fine. React is generally pretty good about performance and state changes, there could be an issue, but probably not.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback buddy, but I want to learn if there is a way to improve it.